# How can I get a list of all fonts used in an Adobe Illustrator file?

Tags: fonts, adobe-illustrator

How can I get a list of all fonts used in an Adobe Illustrator file? Is there a document properties / list of fonts tab that I can access to show all fonts used in an `.ai` file?

Comment: Maybe try to go to `Type > Find Font`.

Comment: @Daria - perfect. Can you post that as the answer?

Comment: Does it really work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe try to go to `Type > Find Font`.

Comment: Specifically in CS6, Type, Find Font and from there you can save the list to a text file.

Comment: Another quick little tip if you want to know the font *sizes* used throughout a document: `Select -> Object -> All Text Objects`, then open the `CSS Properties` pane and click `Generate CSS`. That will give you more than you need and possibly dupes, but you can use your wits and get a concise list from there.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Illustrator CS6 from Creative Cloud (i.e., Illustrator 6.1), you can go to `File -> Package...` .  Deselect everything except "Create Report". The report will list all fonts used in the document.

(This feature will be part of the packaged software in the next major release.)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Illustrator CC, then you can use the builtin 'Package' feature to collect all fonts used in your Illustrator document. If you are using Illustrator CS5 /6, then you can try a third-party Illustrator plugin: [Illustrator Art Packer](http://www.layerhero.com/illustrator-art-packer/)

Answer (score 2):

The Document Info palette will list all the fonts used.

Comment: This is good, but could use a little expansion, how do we get to the document info palette?